# Compare two dataframes based one grain column and print out differences into txt file

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 which different row sizes but same columns, The ID column is common across both dataframes. I want a write the difference in a text file. For example:

df1:

```
ID  Name    Age Profession  sex
1   Tom     20  engineer    M
2   nick    21  doctor      M
3   krishi  19  lawyer      F
4   jacky   18  dentist     F
```

df2:

```
ID  Name    Age Profession  sex
1   Tom     20  plumber     M
2   nick    21  doctor      M
3   krishi  23  Analyst     F
4   jacky   18  dentist     F
```

The resultant text file should look like:

```
ID : 1
Profession_old Profession_new
engineer       plumber

ID : 3
Age_old Age_new Profession_old Profession_new
19      23      lawyer          Analyst
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) and a loop:

```
df3 = df1.set_index('ID').compare(df2.set_index('ID'))

df3.columns = (df3.rename({'self': 'old', 'other': 'new'}, level=1, axis=1)
                  .columns.map('_'.join)
               )

for id, row in df3.iterrows():
    print(f'ID : {id}')
    print(row.dropna().to_frame().T.to_string(index=False))
    print()
```

output:

```
ID : 1
Profession_old Profession_new
      engineer        plumber

ID : 3
Age_old Age_new Profession_old Profession_new
   19.0    23.0         lawyer        Analyst
```

*NB. using print here for the demo, to write to a file:*

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    f.write(f'ID : {id}\n')
    f.write(row.dropna().to_frame().T.to_string(index=False))
    f.write('\n\n')
```

You could also directly use `df3`:

```
    Age_old  Age_new Profession_old Profession_new
ID                                                
1       NaN      NaN       engineer        plumber
3      19.0     23.0         lawyer        Analyst
```

Comment: Great! Kind of what I was looking. 
Would compare still work if an 'ID' is present in df1 and not present in df2?

Comment: @TanmayDutt the two dataframes should have the same indices, if not you need to reindex first, for example: `df3 = df1.set_index('ID').compare(df2.set_index('ID').reindex(df1['ID']))`